# The type or namespace name 'RenderModel' could not be found Unity3d SteamVR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a VR home app for UWP in Unity3D, and I'm getting this error.
The app does the following:

Lists all the users installed apps, and lists their icons in a canvas. When the user clicks on them it opens the app they click on.

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Linq;
using Valve.VR;

public class OpenApp : MonoBehaviour
{
    // reference to the canvas that will display the app icons
    public Canvas appCanvas;

    // reference to the prefab for the app icon buttons
    public Button appIconPrefab;

    // reference to the OpenVR system
    public CVRSystem vrSystem;

    // reference to the OpenVR applications interface
    public IVRApplications vrApps;

    // reference to the app model
    private RenderModel appModel;

    // called when the script is enabled
    public void OnEnable()
    {
        // get the OpenVR system
        vrSystem = OpenVR.System;

        // get the OpenVR applications interface
        vrApps = OpenVR.Applications;

        // get a list of installed apps
        uint appCount = vrApps.GetApplicationCount();
        string[] appList = new string[appCount];
        for (uint i = 0; i < appCount; i++)
        {
            appList[i] = vrApps.GetApplicationKeyByIndex(i, EVRApplicationError.None);
        }

        // sort the app list by app name
        appList = appList.OrderBy(app => app).ToArray();

        // iterate over the app list
        foreach (string appPath in appList)
        {
            // create a new app icon button
            Button appIcon = Instantiate(appIconPrefab);

            // set the parent of the app icon button to the canvas
            appIcon.transform.SetParent(appCanvas.transform);

            // set the position and rotation of the app icon button
            appIcon.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
            appIcon.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;

            // set the app path as the command for the app icon button
                        appIcon.onClick.AddListener(() => LaunchApp(appPath));

            // TODO: set the app icon for the app icon button
            // You can use the RenderModel class to load the app icon, or you can use a different method to retrieve the app icon from the app path.
        }
    }

    // called when the script is disabled
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        // destroy all app icon buttons
        foreach (Transform child in appCanvas.transform)
        {
            Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }

        // destroy the app model
        if (appModel != null)
        {
            Destroy(appModel.gameObject);
        }

        // disable the canvas
        appCanvas.enabled = false;
    }

    // called when an app icon button is clicked
    public void LaunchApp(string appPath)
    {
        try
        {
            // launch the app
            vrApps.LaunchApplication(appPath);

            // create a new RenderModel for the app
            appModel = new RenderModel(appPath);

            // set the canvas as the parent of the app model
            appModel.transform.SetParent(appCanvas.transform);

            // set the position and rotation of the app model
            appModel.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
            appModel.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;

            // enable the canvas
            appCanvas.enabled = true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            // show an error message
            Debug.LogError("Failed to launch app: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried suggestions from chat.openai.com which helped me a lot. I also checked if there where any syntax errors and it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

The RenderModel class is located within the Valve.VR.InteractionSystem namespace.
This one is missing among your list of using statements.